# Theme.translucent is causing errors in my activity

Tags: android

i have two activities, both uses the Theme.Translucent theme, but one works perfectly well while the other causes the error "Unfortunately, has stopped working"

This is the android manifest xml

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.dreama.trafic.SearchActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.dreama.trafic.SearchActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.dreama.trafic.ReportActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.dreama.trafic.ReportActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the layout of the ReportActivity which is the activity that fails when i had this line to its attribute android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/post_edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/post_label"
    android:background="@drawable/editable"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Update your Traffic situation..."
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/location_edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/location_label"
    android:background="@drawable/editable"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Specify your location..." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/location_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/post_edit"
    android:text="Location:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Report:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/category_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/location_edit"
    android:text="Choose Category:" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/category_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sendbutton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/category_spinner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:text="Send Post" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the line calling the activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ReportActivity.class));
```

and this is the logcat when i try to call this activity

```
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
start activity ComponentInfo{com.dreama.trafic/com.dreama.trafic.ReportActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at )
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
com.dreama.trafic.ReportActivity.onCreate(ReportActivity.java:25)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-15 18:34:38.642: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    ... 11 more
```

This is the ReportActivity.java file

```
public class ReportActivity extends Activity {

String[] presidents;




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.report_layout);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents_array);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new          
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
            presidents);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2,
                        long arg3) {   
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You have selected item : 
                           "+ presidents[index],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });


}
```

}

it should be noted that when i run the SearchActivity, it works perfectly but the ReportActivity is the reverse but if i remove the android:theme line,then the activity would display well

Comment: If you remove @android:style/Theme.Translucent from your manifest you don't get the NPE anymore? There has to be more to it than that.

Comment: Can you show us the line(s) of code that the `NPE` is referring to in code?

Comment: i just added all the errors from the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, i removed this lines

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

and it worked perfectly well.